# How to Cisco Anyconnect increase subscription base license user count

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, license

We have Cisco ASA5500 and we purchased `L-AC-PLS-LIC=` for `25` users for 3 year now if i want to increase users count then how can i increase it to `50`?

Can i just buy `25` users license and add into or i have to by brand new `50` users license?  (what will happened to my old 25 users license in that case?)

Interesting enough when i applied 25 users license, its not showing me anywhere that you have `25` users even it is showing `5000`, does that means i have 5000 user limit?

```
fw/pri/act# sh activation-key
Serial Number:  XXXXXX
Running Permanent Activation Key: <I hide this> 

Licensed features for this platform:
Maximum Physical Interfaces       : Unlimited      perpetual
Maximum VLANs                     : 1024           perpetual
Inside Hosts                      : Unlimited      perpetual
Failover                          : Active/Active  perpetual
Encryption-DES                    : Enabled        perpetual
Encryption-3DES-AES               : Enabled        perpetual
Security Contexts                 : 2              perpetual
Carrier                           : Disabled       perpetual
AnyConnect Premium Peers          : 5000           perpetual
AnyConnect Essentials             : Disabled       perpetual
Other VPN Peers                   : 5000           perpetual
Total VPN Peers                   : 5000           perpetual
AnyConnect for Mobile             : Enabled        perpetual
AnyConnect for Cisco VPN Phone    : Enabled        perpetual
Advanced Endpoint Assessment      : Enabled        perpetual
Shared License                    : Disabled       perpetual
Total TLS Proxy Sessions          : 2              perpetual
Botnet Traffic Filter             : Disabled       perpetual
10GE I/O                          : Enabled        perpetual
Cluster                           : Disabled       perpetual
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It is possible for you to buy just another `L-AC-PLS-LIC=` for additional 25 users, thus you will have licenses for 50 users.

   Below information is from [Cisco AnyConnect Ordering Guide (03/2017)](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/security/anyconnect-og.pdf):

   > Note: You are allowed to stack AnyConnect Plus and Apex licenses and terms.

   Please contact Cisco TAC and local Cisco reseller for further advice.
2. AnyConnect 4 Licenses will display as AnyConnect Premium licenses when you issue a ‘show version’ command.

   `AnyConnect Premium Peers : 5000` simply means the maximum number of concurrent SSL VPN, Clientless SSL VPN, and IPsec IKEv1-based remote-access VPN peers/sessions that can terminate on your Cisco ASA platform. And you are right, that is your limit.

   More information you can find on [Cisco Support Forum](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/firewalling/anyconnect-new-licenses-clarification/td-p/2745037) and [here](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0001013)
3. Also from [Cisco AnyConnect Ordering Guide (03/2017)](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/products/collateral/security/anyconnect-og.pdf):

   > Note: For all AnyConnect Plus and Apex licenses, the Adaptive Security Appliance (ASA) license emailed to you
   >   after activating your key will display only the simultaneous hardware user capacity of your appliance, not your
   >   authorized user license count or AnyConnect license tier (Plus or Apex). To look up the user license purchased or
   >   term remaining, please access your support contract through the Cisco Service Contract Center.

   Technically, you can have more than 50 users but would violate the terms of your licenses (please read more [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/vpn/anyconnect-apex-license-question/td-p/2800434))

Comment: when i try to add additional `25` user license and put PAK in Cisco license portal it generate same `activation-key` do you think activation key should be different for two different PAK? which command in Cisco will tell me you have `n` number of users license?

Comment: I do not think they should be different. With this new Cisco Anyconnect license model, you will only see total amount of connections that your ASA platform supports with `show version`. There are no other commands for you to check the number of licensed users. To check this, you have to go to Cisco license portal and/or Cisco Service Contract Center. That means you are all set and I have updated my answer above as well.

Comment: @Satish Please let me know if my answer below is helpful and correct?

Comment: I talked to Cisco support and they said there is not hardware enforcement on ASA, even you have 25 user license you can use 5000 (hardware limit) licensing is just paper term and auditor, it has nothing to do with ASA, once you install any license for anyconnect you can use 5000 users on it no restriction anymore. is that true?

Comment: @Satish That is what I mentioned in point 3 of my answer above `Technically, you can have more than 50 users but would violate the terms of your licenses` You paid for 50 users, you should have 50 users only. If you have more than 50 users, that is fine and NO problem in terms of technical respective, but you would VIOLATE the the terms of your licenses. And I also told you that the number of 5000 is your hardware/platform limit.